# save a record on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, combobox

as you know from my previous questions I'm getting used to rails, currently I have a problem with a create function because it isn't save a record that is in a combobox from the database, like this:

[image]

but it saves the rest of the records in the data base, for check it I type this:

```
rails console
TankingLog.all
TankingLog Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "tanking_logs".* FROM "tanking_logs" 

[#<TankingLog id: 7, car_id: 28, cost: 3000.0, date: "2012-07-30 00:00:00", gallon: 2.0, gas_station_id: nil, km: 5000, created_at: "2012-07-30 22:00:40", updated_at: "2012-07-30 22:00:40">]
```

As you see the gas_station_id field is nil but it must be the id of the station selected
I appreciate any help and sorry if it's a silly question

here is the form:

```
<div class="container">
    <h2>new tanking log</h2>
    <%= form_for ([@user,@car,@tankinglog]) do |f| %>
      <div><%= f.label :cost %><br />
      <%= f.text_field :cost %></div>

      <div><%= f.label :gallon %><br />
      <%= f.text_field :gallon %></div>

      <div><%= f.label :km %><br />
      <%= f.text_field :km %></div>

      <div><%= f.label :date %> <i>( format yyyy-mm-dd )</i> <br />
      <%= f.text_field :date %></div>

      <div><%= f.label :Station %><br />
      <%= select("gas_station", "name", GasStation.all.collect {|gs| [ gs.name, gs.id ] }, { :include_blank => true })%></div>
      <p>
        if you don't see the station that you want, you can <%= link_to "create it", new_gas_station_path%> 
      </p>

      <div><%= f.submit "create tanking",:class => "btn btn-primary" %></div>
    <% end %>
    <br />
    <%= link_to "Back", user_car_tanking_logs_path(@user, @car),:class => "btn btn-primary"%>
  </div>
```

and the tankinglogcontroller

```
class TankingLogsController < ApplicationController
def new
@user = User.find(params[:user_id])  
@car = @user.cars.find(params[:car_id])
@tankinglog = @car.tanking_logs.build
end

def create
@user = User.find(params[:user_id])  
@car = @user.cars.find(params[:car_id])
@tankinglog = @car.tanking_logs.build(params[:tanking_log])
if @tankinglog.save
  redirect_to user_car_tanking_logs_path(@user, @car), :flash => { :notice => "  new tanking created!" }
else
  redirect_to new_user_car_tanking_log_path ,:flash => { :notice => " sorry try again :(" }
end
end
def index
  @user = User.find(params[:user_id]) 
  @car = @user.cars.find(params[:car_id])    
  @tankinglog = @car.tanking_logs.all
end
end
```

if you wanna see the models...

```
class TankingLog < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :gas_station 
belongs_to :car
attr_accessible :car_id, :cost, :date, :gallon, :gas_station_id, :km
validates_presence_of :cost, :date,:gallon,:km
validates_numericality_of :cost, :gallon
validates_numericality_of :km #:only_integer
end


class GasStation < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :tanking_logs
attr_accessible :name
validates_presence_of :name
end
```

Comment: Can you post some relevant code?

Comment: Well please add the code of the form generating the input fields, and the code of the action actually saving the data, as well as the log for the update action

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit this :

```
<%= f.select("gas_station_id", GasStation.all.collect {|gs| [ gs.name, gs.id ] }, { :include_blank => true })%></div>
```